# Java Swing. TextField inside a ScrolPane is not entirely visible

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextfield, jtextarea

I have the structure as you can see in the picture.

For both panels, GridBagLayout is used.
The problem is that the text field inside the scrollpane is not entirely visible.
The parent panel stretches only for the buttons to become visible, but when the scroll bar appears, it just overlap with the text field.
Is there an easy solution to fix this (don't want to deal with setting custom / preferred / minimum heights)?

Panel structure :

[image]

Problem :

[image]

Ok, here is an SSCCE

```
public class Main {
JFrame frame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JTextField someTextTextField;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.show();
}

private void show() {
    frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}


{

    $$$setupUI$$$();
}

/**
 * Method generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
 * >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
 * DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!
 *
 * @noinspection ALL
 */
private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(209, 30));
    final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    mainPanel.add(panel1, gbc);
    button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setText("Button");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel1.add(button1, gbc);
    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setText("Button");
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    panel1.add(button2, gbc);
    final JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane1.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.weighty = 1.0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    mainPanel.add(scrollPane1, gbc);
    someTextTextField = new JTextField();
    someTextTextField.setText("some text");
    scrollPane1.setViewportView(someTextTextField);
}

/**
 * @noinspection ALL
 */
public JComponent $$$getRootComponent$$$() {
    return mainPanel;
}
```

}

Comment: Try adjusting the weighty value of the GridBagConstraint used to layout the scrollpane

Comment: hmm .. is the tree real? That is, is your panel a rendering/editing component? Anyway best to show an SSCCE so we can see what you are actually doing

Comment: no, this is a screenshot of the Intellij IDEA GUI Editor (the first screen)

Comment: after setting the minimum height of the scroll pane it gets solved but I think there should be a more elegant solution

Comment: @Bax: post an SSCCE. Don't use setMinimumHeight

Comment: @Bax: More on [`setXxxSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). Any way to amend the generated code?

Comment: @ trashgod there are a lot of customizable parameters on each component

Answer (score 1):

Try and use a `JTextArea` instead of a `JTextField`. And if you don't want to set custom/preferred/minimum sizes, you can use the `JTextArea.setRows(int rows)` method. I hope that helps.